# Tempdata or Session with respect to server memory consumption

Tags: asp.net-mvc

we are adviced not to use session objects to store everything, I mean just to be careful before storing anything into session to save server memory from excessive use. But there is no such advice on tempdata, however tempdata is also stored in server memory. my question is If we use tempdata and preserve values using keep() and peek() does it make any difference on server memory if we store them in session instead or they are handled in some other way by server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the *same thing*. `TempData` *is* `Session`; the keys related to `TempData` are just cleared after each request.

Comment: Well, technically `Session` is just the default setting of `TempData`. You could always [store `TempData` in cookies](http://brockallen.com/2012/06/11/cookie-based-tempdata-provider/) or somewhere else. Also, the `TempData` is cleared after the first time it is accessed (whether that occurs in the same request, the following request, or 2 requests after it is stored).